# General expression for ratio of polynomials of equal degree and nonzero coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Let $\{a_k\}$ and $\{b_k\}$ be sequences of real and positive constants and $x\in(0,1)$. If we perform polynomial division, we should be able to write this ratio as a single sum.  Is there a known closed expression for the coefficients of this sum? Specifically, is there is closed formula for the coefficients $c_k$ below?
$$
\frac{\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k}{\sum_{k=0}^nb_kx^k}=\sum_{j=0}^n c_kx^{-k}
$$

Comment: Your question is unclear (to me). What would the particular expression be for the quotient $(x+2)/(x+1)$? Please [edit] to show us a few examples of what you are looking for.

Comment: I see your point.  It would seem that I may be looking for the coefficients of the Laurent expansion of the ratio.

Comment: Highly related : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition